# Build GCC 4.4.7 with Error (some warnings being treated as errors)

Tags: gcc, compilation

```
configure flags: --prefix=/nix/store/l06rvwfzdvpabvgzzad4d3zy0pk8rd45-gcc-4.4.7 --disable-multilib --with-ppl=/nix/store/qkydvl67jamj9k2538a7b7467gqx073i-ppl-1.2 --with-cloog=/nix/store/zbn4xs136ccagbjvl7ka8br3f3w9w1gj-cloog-ppl-0.15.11 --with-gmp=/nix/store/7mrq5v4nnqfkv1ka7a0kdw9mzvqs5w3c-gmp-6.1.2 --with-mpfr=/nix/store/9429azblcx1y9apas3azxxd38imcmsy0-mpfr-4.0.2 --disable-libstdcxx-pch --without-included-gettext --with-system-zlib --enable-languages=c\,c++
```

Part of log:

```
../../gcc-4.4.7/libcpp/macro.c:1730:8: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
        cpp_error (pfile, CPP_DL_ERROR, paste_op_error_msg);
        ^~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-4.4.7/libcpp/macro.c:1743:8: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
        cpp_error (pfile, CPP_DL_ERROR, paste_op_error_msg);
        ^~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried to add `CFLAGS=-Wno-error`, but no effect on it. I also tied to use sed to replace `Werror=format-security`, and it also failed.

Comment: How exactly do you invoke `make`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you are using a newer version of compiler (which did not exist at the time of 4.4.7 release) with new and beefed-up warnings.

The language GCC is written in has changed from C to C++ at some point. If that was before 4.4 (not sure; will have to check), then the reason `CFLAGS` has no effect is clear ­— try setting `CXXFLAGS` as well.

(For preserving some history: the answer I originally posted suggested using
`CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET`, which was wrong since libcpp is not a target library and therefore built with the system compiler, not the one just built)

Comment: Yes, I used gcc7 to build this. I have tried `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET` before asking this question here, but building failed. I haven't a gcc with older version. My system is NixOS which has removed supporting for gcc4.4

Comment: @Vonfry, oops, sorry, I was wrong: libcpp is not a target library, but part of the compier itself. But I think I know what the reason for `CFLAGS` having no effect is. I am going to update my answer